# HTML header white space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

for some reason on both sides of my screen on the header I have white space. I have tried to close the margin and padding but it doesn't work. As well, how do you center links on a bootstrap navbar. I tried the bootstrap commands and custom but it won't center.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- JavaScript compile  -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>VE Website</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Joaquin Frommer">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>
    <style>

    html,body{
        height: auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .carousel,.item,.active{
        height: auto;}
    .carousel-inner{
        height: auto;}
    .img{
        height:auto; width:100%}
    .navbar-default {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #e5b984;  
        z-index: 99999;

    }
    .navbar {
        min-height: 20px;
        }

    .navbar-brand {
     height: 20px; line-height: 20px;
        }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #703d41;
        }

    .nav-item:hover{
        background-color: #fff0bb;
        color: #703d41;
        }

    .nav-item{
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 85px;
        padding-right: 85px; 
        }
    .navbar-nav li a {

        line-height: 20px;
        }
    .navbar-header a {

        line-height:20px;
        }

    .carousel{
        position: relative;

    }


    header{
        background-image: url(skyline.jpg); 
        left:0; 
        right:0; 
        width:100%;
    }

    h1{
        margin:0; 
        padding:0; 
        right:0; 
        left:0; 
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
            $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 10000,
          pause: "false",
          wrap: "true"
          });
        var $item = $('.carousel .item');
        var $wHeight = $(window).height();


        $item.height($wHeight); 
        $item.addClass('full-screen');

        $('.carousel img').each(function() {
          var $src = $(this).attr('src');
          var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
          $(this).parent().css({
            'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
            'background-color' : $color
          });
          $(this).remove();
        });

        $(window).on('resize', function (){
          $wHeight = $(window).height();
          $item.height($wHeight);
        });
          $item.eq(0).addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
    <div class="container-fluid body">
        <header>
            <center>
            <h1 class="img-responsive"><img style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-position: center center;" src="logoNomad.png" height="97" width="97"></h1>
            </center>
        </header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="fixedstuff">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"href="#">CHARITY</a></li> 
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"href="#">RESERVE</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"href="#">ACOUNTS</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="image2.jpg" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>First Image</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="image1.jpg" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Second Image</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Third image Image</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fourth Image</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700" data-color="firebrick" alt="Second Image" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Fifth Image</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>here
```

Comment: Please use the code snippet function.

Answer (score 0):

Its because container-fluid class adds padding of 15px on both sides.
just create a nopadding class and add besides the container-fluid class.

```
.nopadding{
padding-left:0;
padding:right:0;
}

<div class="container-fluid nopadding">...</div>
```

as for centering the links add bootstrap's "text-center" class to your links, make sure you use media queries else they will centered for all devices

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-center" href="#">HOME</a></li>
```

Comment: the no padding worked but my navbar is still not centered with the center text. Using the center text centers them individually, i need it to be all of them aligned. I already tried alignment on the ul and navbar too.